# jQuery: find() not working when get feed

Tags: jquery, get, find

I'm making recent post widget for Blogger by getting feed and this is my code:

```
$("#recentpost .widget-content").each(function () {
    var a = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + a + "?alt=json-in-script",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (h) {
            var m = "";
            var e = '<ul>';
            for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                for (var g = 0; g < h.feed.entry[k].link.length; g++) {
                    if (h.feed.entry[k].link[g].rel == "alternate") {
                        m = h.feed.entry[k].link[g].href;
                        break
                    }
                }
                if ('media$thumbnail' in h.feed.entry[k]) {
                    var l = h.feed.entry[k].media$thumbnail.url.replace("s72-c", "s215-c");
                    var b = '<img src="' + l + '"/>';
                };
                var f = h.feed.entry[k].author[0].name.$t;
                var c = h.feed.entry[k].title.$t;
                var d = h.feed.entry[k].published.$t.substring(0, 10);
                e += '<li><a href="' + m + '"><div class="thumbrc">' + b + '</div><h3 class="title">' + c + '</h3></a><div class="footerpost"><span>' + d + " - " + f + "</span></div></li>"
            }
            e += '</ul><div class="clear"/>';
            $("#recentpost .widget-content").each(function () {
                var j = $(this).text();
                if (j == a) {
                    $(this).html(e);
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

But, there a problem, when i use the code below to get thumbnail for post which do not have img on Picasa host, the code doesn't work.

```
var content = h.feed.entry[k].content.$t;
var l = $(content).find("img:first").attr("src");
```

Help me fix it, please. Thank you very much.

Comment: _"the code doesn't work"_ - Where are you trying to use that code? And  when you say "doesn't work" does that mean you get an error in the browser's console, or something happens but it's the wrong thing, or nothing seems to happen at all, or...? (And as an aside, your code is pretty hard to read because you don't use meaningful variable names. It's pretty standard to use `i` and `j` for loop counters, and perhaps `l` for holding the length of something and `e` as an error object, but you've got one-letter variables everywhere and it's hard to keep track of what they're for.)

Comment: What is `h.feed.entry[k].content.$t` ?